# Google analytics report more user than installed number

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I released a game on play store with Google analytics integrated via Firebase. Now after a new days, GA says that I have over 300 "new users" in "Acquisition" tab. But based on my play console, I just have about 15 installation. The numbers are not remotely close to suspect delay issues, or uninstalls.

I wonder if I do something wrong, or otherwise what is the cause of this?